# How to split multiple string formats using regex and assigning its different groups to variable

Tags: php, python, regex, variables, split

I can't seem to get this correct.

I have this PHP command that I need to do the same thing in Python:

```
preg_match("/^(collabedge-|cb|ss)([0-9]+).dc-([0-9]+).com$/", $domain, $matches);
```

I have three possible string formats:

```
domain = collabedge-123.dc-01.com
domain = cb123.dc-01.com
domain = ss123.dc-01.com
```

I need to pull out the 123 and 01 from the string no matter what the format of the string and assign to variables.

Comment: If you have a specific Python related issue, please post the code that fails, and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks the answers are below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
import re

domain = "collabedge-123.dc-01.com"
# preg_match("/^(collabedge-|cb|ss)([0-9]+).dc-([0-9]+).com$/", $domain, $matches);
regex = r"^(collabedge-|cb|ss)([0-9]+).dc-([0-9]+).com$"
res = re.match(regex,domain)
print(res.group(0))
print(res.group(1))
print(res.group(2))
print(res.group(3))
```

Output:

```
collabedge-123.dc-01.com
collabedge-
123
01
```

Comment: Thanks, as I was posting below you had already answered quickly before I saw it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As sure as I posted the question I kept trying and figured it out. For those that want to know the answer.

```
d = re.match(r"(collabedge-|cb|ss)([0-9]+)\.dc-([0-9]+)\.com",  domain)
firstnum = d.group(2)
secnum = d.group(3)
```